# How do I give bibliographical reference to html code I discovered on the net in my html code?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been jotting down bibliographical references to where I found out how to do something in html or JavaScript in my html comment tags but am not sure if this is best way to do it in html5.

like:

```
<!-- Subject: Puts widget in doodad, Found on: www on Oct 5th, 2013 at 2:00am @ www.anbender.com/insanely/awesome/htmlcode.html -->
```

Is there a best practices for this as I not only want to use references but also need to generate a bibliographical reference in my website's html?

The reason is because just started using a new JavaScript frameworks like angular, knockout, others and need a way to track the references in my code to meet compliance standards down the road and to create a best practices list with biographical references for some of the references.

Comment: What compliance standards down the road? I haven't heard of any that require citing the sources of used libraries (beyond paying for non-free ones as per licenses)

Comment: Just drink the Koolaid standards like ANSI/NISO Z39.29-2005 and also part of CMMI.  Not required just good for a government agency to know that you are following a protocol for gathering biographical references.

Comment: Perhaps you're right, but this leaves open the possibility to find a good case.  Someone just needs to answer it and I need to hit the little green checkmark and Walla.

Comment: This is a good question. I hope someone cites a few references and summarizes the consensus among sources. There are a few fragmented hits on other Stack Exchange sites: [www.google.com/#q=how+to+cite+source+code+site:stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+cite+source+code+site:stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is the problem with this site, too many farmers and fishermen and not enough damned coders.

Answer (score 2):

At least within the US, this is not based on one centralized standard, but rather completely determined by the entity who owns the "copyright" to to content. They could impose almost arbitrary terms for the use of their content.

Normally you can assume the "copyright owner" is the person that is publishing it, but technically there is no way to know 100% for sure. (Gee thanks, copyright law :D )

Anyway, once you have determined who the "copyright owner" is, you need to determine how they say you can use their content. If their code is intended for third-party use, this is frequently in the format of a "license" that is included directly with the code which governs how you can use it (including requirements to reference the source). If you can't find it, you should contact the owners and ask them in writing for rights to use their code, and reference this granted permission.

- In the case of "copyleft" licenses like Creative Commons, GNU, MIT, they will normally specify how they must be attributed, and it typically involves providing a whole copy of the license along with the code.
- In the case of content that has been released into the public domain, I suggest you check out the language that they use on wikipedia (e.g. when looking at any image) and copy that
- In the case of "copyright" licenses there is typically a requirement to both note that it's copyrighted, referencing the copyright owner, and that basically no right is granted to use/reproduce/modify the content.

Comment: I think you're confusing copyright and license with RetroCoder's desire to simply cite a reference.